# determining the quadrant if else

Tags: c

So, I was trying to make a program to determine what quadrant an ordered pair is in, I haven't accounted if it sits the the axes or if it's on the point of origin. But anyway no matter what number I input it always prints first or second quadrant. It must be because of the "else's" but I can't figure out why that doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x, y;
printf("Enter an X value and a Y value ");
scanf("%i,%i\n",&x,&y);
if (x>= 1)
    if (y>= 1)
        printf("Lies in the First Quadrant");
    else
        printf("Lies in the Fourth Quadrant");
else if (x <= -1)
    if (y >= 1)
        printf("Lies in the Second Quadrant");
    else
        printf("Lies in the Third Quadrant"); }
```

Comment: Hint: use more curly braces :-)

Comment: What were the exact keys you pressed on your keyboard for the X and Y values?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`! Otherwise you won't know if `x` and `y` were even assigned.

Comment: The `'\n'` in `scanf("%i,%i\n",&x,&y);` will cause trouble.  [Ditch](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ditch) `scanf()`, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%i,%i\n",&x,&y);`

I had put a comma in between the `%i`'s, but I wasn't typing in the comma when I was inputing it :/